# Detect user login in Windows Domain Controller

Tags: windows, login, logging, windows-server-2012, event-log

I'm trying to detect a user login event in Windows DC (Win Server 2012), but i'm having the following issues:

- The event [4624](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/auditing/event-4624) is not really certain because it might be automatically generated. For example when the [Group Policy is automatically refreshed](https://www.eventtracker.com/newsletters/account-logon-and-logonlogoff/).
- The local computer might have cached the credentials for the user so the user logon is not detected by the DC.

My main goal is to detect when a user access to his computer outside from work hours, that is user having activity between 22pm-7am. Also, my only data source is .evtx files generated in Domain Controller.

Comment: Something to consider potentially would be to make the user accounts use a login script and add some logic in that to have something put into a log file on a hidden share or something. Another thing to consider is to disallow login at specific times for specific accounts in AD Users and Computers if they are not supposed to log in during those times you can actually enforce a policy to prevent that entirely instead of having to dig in a log, find out who did this, report it or talk to them about it, etc. after the fact. Just a couple quick thoughts on the topic.

Comment: Do you have more than one DC? If so, you'd have to monitor all of them for logon events unless you can guarantee which DC will be used to authenticate the user.

Comment: If your **only** data source is event log data from a DC, then you **do not** have access to enough information to capture *all* relevant logon events. Are you certain you cannot include events captured by the user's workstation in your query?

Comment: There are many workstations, i might think in a solution using a log hub, is that posible without using third party tools?

Comment: Diego - You say ***"My main goal is to detect when a user access to his computer outside from work hours"*** so I'm curious what will be done with this data you gather that has the logins during these non-work hours? Additionally, you could setup a login script to run that if it cannot find the DC or hidden share that it logs to a local log file, & then have logic in there that also states if the hidden share is available, copy over the latest local login file to the same share but a separate subfolder perhaps and have the log name be `%computername%.log` perhaps.This would show cached logins.

Comment: The "out of hour access" is allowed for my users. But, i must monitor if they access a lot. Let's say 1 or 2 access per month is right, but more than 10 is suspicious activity. If the script can write directly in the windows event file that would be awesome, and that would be my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, the DC does not capture logins on a remote computer with cached credentials, as the computer may not always be physically connected to the domain.  Instead, you'll have to check his computer directly while his computer is online.

> You can use the Event Viewer or the wevtutil command at a command
>   prompt to manage event logs on a remote computer.
>
> 1. Start Event Viewer.
> 2. Click the root node, for example **Event Viewer (Local)**, in the console tree.
> 3. On the **Action** menu, click **Connect to Another Computer**
> 4. In the **Another computer box**, type the name or IP address of the remote computer.
> 5. (Optional) Select **Connect as another user**, click **Set User**, enter the **User name** and **Password**, and then click **OK**
> 6. Click **OK**
>
> Source: [Work with Event Logs on a Remote Computer - Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766438(v=ws.11).aspx)

Search for [Event 4648 - A logon was attempted using explicit credentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/auditing/event-4648)  on his computer.

As the description says, it is only when a logon uses explicit credentials.  This event is generated on logging in or unlocking even with saved credentials (ie: Remote Desktop).

Note: As with any event, you can do additional filtering to remove any automatically generated events (less common with 4648 and username).  The GUI (on the Filter tab) provides filtering on some fields.  Using the XML tab, you can filter on any field within the event.

Comment: 4648 is not getting the login from the workstations in the domain, it's just getting the logins that are explicitly in the Server (DC).

Comment: You will likely have to check logs on his computer.  See edited answer.